# Problem solving the hexagon that's inscribed in a circle

Tags: geometry, polygons

The hexagon $ABCDEF$ is encoded in a circle. $|AF| = 31$ and the other five sides have lengths $81$. Determine the sum of the lengths of the hexagonal diagonals starting from $A$ $(|AC|+|AD|+|AE|)$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort.

Comment: Well, why don't you know what the answer is?  What knowledge do you or don't you have about hexagons?  You know the sides of the hexagon are equal, what about the angles? Do you know if you can or can not assume the hexagon is regular.  If you know the side of a regular hexagon to you know the diagonal?  If the hexagon is regular is there some formula for diagonals.  This is a *VERY* straightforward question, and its impossible to help unless we know precisely what you DON'T know.

Comment: Hint: Cut the hexagon into smaller triangles.

Comment: Hello, thanks. I tried to upload a picture of what I drew but couldn't upload it since I'm new here. I've drawn a point in the center of the circle and then I drew lines from the center to each corner. Then I have 5 angles that I call alpha and I have one angle I call beta. So 5a+ b= 360. I also have 81^2=2*r(1-cos(a)) and 31^2=2*r(1-cos(b))=2*r(1-cos(360-5a))=2*r(1-cos(-5a))=2*r(1-cos(5a)). After this I can't solve it and I don't know if this is the right way to go

Comment: If I get the angle a or b or what the radius is I can solve the rest but I don't know how to get one of them from this information

Comment: Hint: Use [Ptolemy's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ptolemy%27s_theorem) a few times.

Comment: #dxiv, I've tried to use ptolemy's theorem but I get more unknown variables compared to number of equations

Comment: Solved it using ptolemy's theorem on ADEF, ACEF and ACDE. Thanks for the help guys, especially to you dxiv :)